# How to pass value from one method into main method?

Tags: java

I'm creating a math program that asks the user how many digits they'd like to use, then asks them what kind of math they want to do. It then asks the user 10 math questions based on their answers. It then decides if they're right or wrong and displays an appropriate message. It then calculates their percentage of correct answers and displays a message based on the percentage.

The problem is that the program never stops after 10 questions and never calculates the percentage or displays the final message. I believe this is at least partially occurring because I'm not passing the new "answeredTyped" value from the "askQuestion" method. Can someone explain how I can easily pass this new value back to the main method so that it'll stop at 10? Or perhaps tell me what else is keeping this from working correctly?

I've asked quite a few questions about this program already, so I appreciate everyone's patience with me learning Java and having very little knowledge of the language.

Thank you for any help! (also I apologize for any bad formatting here! After changing about a million things, it got ugly)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Assignment2 {
    public static int answeredTyped = 0;
    public static int correctAnswers = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int difficulty = 1;
        String[] operators = { "plus", "minus", "times", "divided by" };
        int selectedOperator = 1;



        int difficultyInput = Integer
                .parseInt(JOptionPane
                        .showInputDialog("Please choose the difficulty. Enter the number of digits to use in each problem."));

        if (difficultyInput > 0) {
            difficulty = difficultyInput;
        }
        int arithmeticMethod = Integer
                .parseInt(JOptionPane
                        .showInputDialog("Choose an arithmetic problem to study: 1 = Addition Only, 2 = Subtraction Only, 3 = Multiplication Only, 4 = Division Only, 5 = Random Problems"));

        selectedOperator = arithmeticMethod;

        new Assignment2().askQuestion(difficulty, null, selectedOperator,
                answeredTyped, operators, correctAnswers);

        while (answeredTyped < 10) {
            askQuestion(difficulty, null, selectedOperator, answeredTyped,
                    operators, correctAnswers);
            answeredTyped++;


            if (answeredTyped>= 10) {
                if (((float) correctAnswers / answeredTyped) >= 0.75) {
                    JOptionPane
                            .showMessageDialog(null,
                                    "Congratulations, you are ready to go on to the next level!");
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Please ask your teacher for extra help.");
                }
        }
    }
    }

    public static boolean checkResponse(double primaryInt, double secondaryInt,
            String operatorText, double response) {
        if (operatorText.equals("plus")) {
            return (primaryInt + secondaryInt) == response;
        } else if (operatorText.equals("minus")) {
            return (primaryInt - secondaryInt) == response;
        } else if (operatorText.equals("times")) {
            return (primaryInt * secondaryInt) == response;
        } else if (operatorText.equals("divided by")) {
            return (primaryInt / secondaryInt) == response;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static String displayResponse(boolean isCorrect) {
        int randomIndex = (int) (Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - 1 + 1)) + 1);
        switch (randomIndex) {
        case 1:
            return isCorrect ? "Very Good!" : "No. Please try again.";
        case 2:
            return isCorrect ? "Excellent!" : "Wrong. Try once more.";
        case 3:
            return isCorrect ? "Nice Work!" : "Don\'t give up!";
        case 4:
            return isCorrect ? "Keep up the good work!" : "No. Keep trying.";
        }
        return "Oops...";
    }

    public static void askQuestion(int difficulty, String operatorText,
            int selectedOperator, int answeredTyped, String[] operators,
            int correctAnswers) {
        boolean correctAnswer = false;
        double primaryInt = Math.floor(Math.pow(10, difficulty - 1)
                + Math.random() * 9 * Math.pow(10, difficulty - 1));
        double secondaryInt = Math.floor(Math.pow(10, difficulty - 1)
                + Math.random() * 9 * Math.pow(10, difficulty - 1));

        operatorText = (selectedOperator == 5) ? operators[(int) Math
                .floor(Math.random() * operators.length)]
                : operators[selectedOperator - 1];


            double response = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog("How much is " + primaryInt + " "
                            + operatorText + " " + secondaryInt + "?"));
            correctAnswer = checkResponse(primaryInt, secondaryInt,
                    operatorText, response);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, displayResponse(correctAnswer));
 if (correctAnswer)
                correctAnswers++;

            }

        }
```

Comment: Not related to your question, do you use an IDE? Most IDEs have built in formatters. If you are using Eclipse, press `ctrl+shift+F` to format your code.

Comment: I believe it's ctrl+I for eclipse, and alt+shift+f for netbeans. (though perhaps there's a ctrl+shift+f for eclipse).

Comment: I usually use Eclipse, but I'm actually in NetBeans right now. Thanks for the hint! Also thank you for going ahead and formatting this for me :)

Comment: @Rogue: I just checked eclipse, ctrl+I is only for indentation. ctrl+shift+F is for a total formatting (eg, adding linebreaks.)

Comment: Alright guys, I changed my code in the OP to reflect my new code. It now stops after 10, but it never does give me the final message. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two while loops, so it will call askQuestion() ten times, and then there is askQuestion's own while loop:

main()

```
while (answeredTyped < 10) {
```

askQuestion()

```
while (!correctAnswer && answeredTyped < 10) {
```

Try using only a single while loop, and putting the evaluation of the answers in total outside of the askQuestion() method

Comment: I tried deleting the second while loop you mentioned(just deleted that line), but it still does the same thing . What exactly do you mean by " putting the evaluation of the answers in total outside of the askQuestion() method"? What part of the code would go outside of the askQuestion() method, and where exactly would it go? Just right after the last bracket of that method?

Comment: What I meant is that you have a `while` loop that runs askQuestion() ten times, and then within askQuestion(), it looks like you ask the question ten times and evaluate the test overall in each iteration. So at this point, you're running a 10-question test 10 times, which means you evaluate the 10 tests 100 times total. Try evaluating everything after the entire test (for instance, askQuestion() could return an int value of the number of correct questions ;) )

Comment: I changed my code in the OP to reflect my new code. It now stops after 10, but it never does give me the final message. With the new code I just let the main method call askQuestion() 10 times and askQuestion asks one question at a time. I'm sure this is bad technique, but I'm so sick of this thing by this point that I just want to get it working any way possible. Any tips on getting the final message to show with my new code?

Comment: You do a check for `if (correctAnswers >= 10)` which will never happen unless you get a perfect score. Try using <= 10 instead.

Comment: Ah you inadvertently found my problem! That was just supposed to be answeredTyped instead of correctAnswers. Switched it and it now displays the message at the end. Only problem is that it displayed the wrong message when I got all 10 right. Any ideas? (Sorry to keep going with this, you're just being extremely helpful to me and I greatly appreciate it)

Comment: Try adding debug code and printing out values you obtain. for example what `(float) correct / answers`(pseudo) would evaluate to. Simply try to verify everything works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

You have to increment answeredType in the while loop of the main method,not within another method,since you have not declared the variable as global

Comment: I changed my code in the OP to reflect my new code. It now stops after 10, but it never does give me the final message. Any tips? I declared it as global in hopes it would help